# Propagating settings from the Settings page on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app in which I have two pages.  First is the MainPage.xaml in which I am using a longlistselector control to show a list.  On the Settings.xaml page, I have a font size selection for the user using the Listpicker control.

The question is, once the user selects a new font size on the Settings page, I want to change the font in the longlistselector on MainPage.  However, a longlistselector decaled on the MainPage.xaml is not available on the Settings page. (I am setting the itemssource of the longlistselector in the MainPage.cs file.)

How should I resolve this issue?  Should I use a page event of MainPage.xaml and detect if a font size has been changed by the user?  What is the standard way of tackling this problem?

XAML in Settings.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Select Font" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <toolkit:ListPicker Name="fontlistpicker" Tap="fonttapped" Margin="0,35,0,0" Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="fontlistpicker_SelectionChanged">
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="Font1" Content="10"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="Font2" Content="20"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="Font3" Content="30"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="Font4" Content="40"/>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="Font5" Content="50"/>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

XAML in MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="myList" >
<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
     <TextBlock  Name ="dailyHeader" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Can you tell if the solution provided has worked for you? If yes, please mark it as the correct answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate away from the Settings.xaml page you can use OnNavigatedFrom() method to save your settings to IsolatedStorageSettings. Then in the MainPage.xaml in code behind in the OnNavigatedTo() method you can load that settings Value from The IsolatedStorageSettings and set the font in  your LongListSelector. That is the way to Do it. In your Settings page, Add the following code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    string key = "Font-Size";
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key] = (fontlistpicker.SelectedItem as ListPickerItem).Content.ToString();
}
```

then in the MainPage.xaml.cs file Add the following

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Font-Size"))
    {
        string fontSize = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Font-Size"] as string;     

        // Code to set the Font size of your LongListSelector
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this should work just fine.  But I just thought this would be less efficient as this event would fire even if settings do not change and I would be updating the font regardless...

Comment: You have another option in my view. you can have a simple variable or an object in App.xaml.cs file. So it has an application scope. And when ever you go to the settings page and set the value in the valueChanged event in the appropriate controller you set that value as the desired value in the variable/object in App.xaml.cs and then you can access that anywhere in the app. And when you terminate the app. save that value to IsolatedStorageSetting. That too will work for you.